Where is ... (ellipsis) supposed to be placed in a C++ parameter pack expansion? Inside or outside of the parenthesis for std::forward?
I am new to C++ parameter pack expansion, and I have been confused about the position of ... (ellipsis) for a long time, eg:
template <typename... Args> 
void func(Args&&... args) {
    // ...
    std::forward<Args>(args)...;
    // ...
}

Why isn't there std::forward<Args>(args...)? What is the rule I should follow?

Exact Dupe: What are the rules for the "..." token in the context of variadic templates?

@user12002570 nice dupe. I couldn't find it because it didn't have [tag:pack-expansion]. I think we should apply this tag a bit more to make deduplication easier in the future.

@JanSchultke Thanks, I searched for the phrase "where should the ellipsis in pack expansion of std::forward go" and google didn't disappoint. I usually first search google and then search SO(if google can't find anything relevant) based on tags etc(as you did). I agree with the applying this tag a bit more.

Check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack, particularly the "Pack expansion" section.
Basically, the "..." in the pack expansion is almost like a macro: it creates more source code, in a way. Whatever is before the "..." just gets repeated for each argument (and the pack-name replaced with said argument), so something like func(args...) would be expanded as "func(a, b, c)", while func(args)... would turn into "func(a), func(b), func(c)".
std::forward just takes one argument and produces one forwarded item: func(std::forward(args)...) will turn into a list of individual forwards: func(std::forward(a), std::forward(b), std::forward(c)). So, it takes a list of arguments, and produces a list of forwarded arguments

I am reading the chapter. It is clear combined with your explanation. Thank you so much!

it's weird to me that cpprefrence fails to render syntax for pack expansion. It's way more flexible than they show.

Grammatically, std::forward<Args>(args)...; doesn't make sense.
You can only use a pack expansion within parentheses or braces.
If you were to call a function, say foo, then you would write:
foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)

This would be a postfix-expression foo(/* ... */), which contains an expression-list, which is an initializer-list with a single initializer-clause std::forward<Args>(args) and a ....
In other words, the ... isn't part of the expression; it's part of the list of expressions.
Therefore, ... is the "outermost" thing, as it has lower precedence than any expression.
*args... and args()... would apply * and () to each argument in args respectively.
You can think of X... as an instruction that says:

Do X for each element in the pack.

std::forward<Args>(args...) is wrong because the ... here applies to the initializer-list of arguments when calling std::forward, but std::forward is not a variadic function template.
Instead of forwarding each argument, it attempts to call std::forward with the whole pack passed in.
See also How would one call std::forward on all arguments in a variadic function?
